# Sum of the values with similar index

Tags: c++, c++11, io

Suppose I have a set of 1000 statistical data in a text file. The first column of which represents the number of index, and second column represents the value of that. The index can be repeated and the corresponding values can be different. I would like to count the occurrence of the indexes and the sum of the values for each of them.

I write a code which gives the results for occurrence of the indexes but it fails to gives the corresponding sum of the values.

**Example**

Suppose my text file has a set of data like this-

```
#index   value
  4      0.51
  5      0.13
  5      0.53
  5      0.25
  6      0.16
  6      0.16
  7      0.38
  4      0.11
  3      0.101
  4      0.32
  4      0.2 ... and more
```

So in this case-

Index 4 **occurs** 4 times and the corresponding **sum** of the values = (0.51+0.11+0.32+0.2) = 1.14

Similarly

Index 5 **occurs** 2 times and the **sum** of values = (0.13+0.53)= 0.66 etc.

**My Code**

Here is my code-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    map<double,double>   index;
    double  number,value;
    double total;


    ifstream theFile ("a1.txt");
    while(theFile >> number >> value)
    {
        ++index[number];
        total +=value;
    }
    cout<<"index\t occurs\t total"<<endl;


    for(auto loop = index.begin(); loop != index.end();++loop)
    {
         cout << loop->first << "\t  " << loop->second << "\t \t "<< total<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code generates the results-

```
index  occurs  total
3       1     2.851
4       4     2.851
5       3     2.851
6       2     2.851
7       1     2.851
```

Though the number of occurrence   are correct but the

> total +=value;

does not generates the output I am looking for. How can I get the sum for each of the indexes?

Comment: Your total appears to count the total of each entry in the whole file instead of each individual index.  In a similar way that you accumulate the 'occurs' columns, you would want to accumulate the 'total' column.

Comment: @ChrisCooper: How can accumulate the total column? Could you please help me with a pseudo code?

Comment: I'm writing an answer now.

Comment: Your should probably also note on top of everything else the comment-line is *not* automagically ignored by your loop accumulation. You can either ignore the the first line via an unused `std::getline()` or special-handle the lines one at a time and ignore anything starting with a `'#'` character. Either way, it needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your total currently only counts the total in the whole file instead of the total for each index.  In a similar way that you accumulate the 'occurs' column, you would want to accumulate the 'total' column.  See your code modified below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<double, double> index;
    double number, value;
    map<double, double> total;

    ifstream theFile ("a1.txt");
    while(theFile >> number >> value)
    {
        ++index[number];
        total[number] += value;
    }

    cout << "index\t occurs\t total" << endl;
    for(auto loop = index.begin(); loop != index.end();++loop)
    {
        cout << loop->first << "\t  " << loop->second << "\t \t "<< total[loop->first] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am storing each column in its own total map in the same way you store the index in its own map.

Answer (score 7):

1. You need a `total` per index.
2. You need a `count` per index.

The simple solution for this is to use the following structure:

```
struct per_index
{
   int count;
   double total;
   per_index(): total(0), count(0) {}
};

std::map<int, per_index> index;

...

index[number].count++;
index[number].total += value;
```

Note that I don't believe your `number` that you read should (or need to) be a `double`, and it just makes life more complex, since `double` has difficulties in comparing for equality. So I've gone for `number` being an `int` - you will need to change the declaration in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding `value` to `total` for **every** index, whereas you need a separate `total` for each index.

A map of indexes to a vector of values matching it would be simplest, so you can then do the sum for each index in a separate step.

The body of your reading loop can be something like

```
index[ number ].push_back( value );
```

Then loop over all the entries in index producing the sum of the elements in its associated vector. (Hint - `accumulate` is a common name for that....)

EDIT: Oh, and the count is obviously the number of elements in each vector.

Comment: Since the OP is only interested in accumulated totals for each index (and the occurrence count) there is no need for a separate vector for each index. A simple count and accumulated total will suffice.